# Executable Windows permission on Samba

Tags: windows, permissions, samba, executable

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 (though I've had this same problem on 12.10) and am running Samba with some shares set up so I can run some Windows tools (.exes) directly from the shares. Every Windows computer I've tried to run the programs on from the share give a permission error.

The shares are read-only, have guest access and are created simply through the "Share" tab of Nautilus properties. If I check the box "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder", they are able to execute fine, but this isn't ideal. There's no issue reading any other type of file or even copying the .exes over to a temporary location on the Windows machine and running it. Changing the executable bit makes no difference (desperate!).

Thanks.

Comment: Let me get this straight.. You have set all file and folder permissions correctly and the user has the rights to read write and execute, but it still doesn't work? Could you show what your ls -Al output is on a shared folder?

Comment: @Bart.a The permissions for everything in the shared folders are `rwxrwxrwx` with root as the owner (they reside on an NTFS volume mounted by an fstab entry). To make it a bit more clear, my goal is to simply be able to plug a stray Windows machine on to the same network and be able to run myprogram.exe located in `\\ubuntu-pc\mypublicshare` without having to provide any credentials. I can get as far as navigating to the share on the Windows client, but when I try to run the .exe, I get a permission error from Windows.

Comment: Strange.. Could it be you have a configuration error in your smb.conf file? Have you added the value 'guest ok = yes' to your share? I think it's an authentication problem. Would it be a problem to add a samba user without a password? You could log in with that very easily and remember it on each stray machine..